# How to commit output from private workflow to another public repo

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need to commit the output from my private repo workflow ( github-actions) to a public repo is it possible?

Comment: Could you give more details about the context, what you tried, and what you want to do exactly? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be possible using standard git tools. Add something like this to your workflow:

```
cd wherever_your_output_resides
# clone the public repo, or pull if we have a clone already
git pull origin || git clone <url> .
# check out the desired branch (optional)
git checkout some_branch
# stage output
# (you may need to tweak this, e.g. to include files not in the index yet)
git add --all
# commit
git commit -m "<message for the commit>"
# push to the remote repo
git push origin
```

git commands are off the top of my head; you might want to do a dry-run of these until everything works smoothly.

Comment: Hi, i tried this getting "Error: Process completed with exit code 1"

Comment: Then check the console output. Find out which of the commands triggered the error, and what the error message was. As I said, you might want to doi a dry-run of those (e.g. try them out on your local system against a dummy repository) to make sure everything works smoothly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)